# Spring @Transactional

Tags: spring, junit, transactions

I'm trying to put together a bare-bones minimalist JUnit test for a system using Spring @Transactional annotations, and not having much success.

I'm creating two instances with the same value for a column that has a unique constraint.  If the two instance creations happen to be in different transactions, I expect that the first will commit and the second will throw an exception, leading to one row -- and I see that happening.  If the two inserts happen in the same Transaction, I expect both to be rolled back as an atomic unit, which I'm not seeing.  I'm sure that there's a configuration issue somewhere, but I've not had much luck identifying it.

For the test I have a bean (ContextTestHelperImpl / ContextTestHelper) with methods to create either one or two instances.  Each has a Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW annotation on the method:

```java
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, 
        rollbackFor = {ContextDuplicationException.class})
public Foo createOneFoo(int val) throws ContextDuplicationException {
    try {
        return fooDAO.createFoo(val);
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        throw new ContextDuplicationException(th);
    }
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, 
        rollbackFor = {ContextDuplicationException.class})
public Foo[] createTwoFoos(int val) throws ContextDuplicationException {
    try {
        return new Foo[] { fooDAO.createFoo(val), fooDAO.createFoo(val) };
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        throw new ContextDuplicationException(th);
    }
}
```

I have one JUnit test (ContextTest) which calls the first method twice:

```java
public void dupTestTwoTransactions() {
    contextTestHelper.deleteAllFoo();
    Assert.assertEquals(0, contextTestHelper.getCountOfFoo());

    boolean hadException = false;
    try {
        contextTestHelper.createOneFoo(DUPLICATE_VALUE);
    } catch (ContextDuplicationException th) {
        hadException = true;
        System.out.println("[ContextTest][dupTestTwoTransactions] UNEXPECTED ERROR: " + th);
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(hadException, false);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, contextTestHelper.getCountOfFoo());

    try {
      contextTestHelper.createOneFoo(DUPLICATE_VALUE);
    } catch (ContextDuplicationException th) {
        hadException = true;
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(hadException, true);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, contextTestHelper.getCountOfFoo());
}
```

This works as expected.  The first call doesn't throw an exception; the second call does.  At the end of it all, there's one row in the Foo table.

I have a second JUnit test in the same class which calls the latter method once:

```java
@Test
public void dupTestOneTransaction() {
    contextTestHelper.deleteAllFoo();
    Assert.assertEquals(0, contextTestHelper.getCountOfFoo());

    boolean hadException = false;
    try {
      contextTestHelper.createTwoFoos(DUPLICATE_VALUE);
    } catch (ContextDuplicationException th) {
        hadException = true;
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(hadException, true);
    Assert.assertEquals(0, contextTestHelper.getCountOfFoo());
}
```

This second test fails on the final assertion -- the count of Foo instances is 1, while I'm expecting 0.

I have a little bit of shenanigans going on with the data source setup because we're trying to use a JNDI lookup for when the code runs under JBoss.  As a result, JUnit needs to set up the JNDI lookup behind the scenes (ContextTest.java):

```java
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws NamingException {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-test.xml");
    DataSource testDataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("testDataSource");
    SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
    builder.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource", testDataSource);
    builder.activate();
}
```

Here is my spring-test.xml file which in NetBeans is set up in the Test Packages' default package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="user-specific.properties"/>

<bean id="testDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${db.driver.class}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${db.url}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${db.user}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${db.password}</value></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Since the first test works, I'm clearly able to connect to the database, so I don't think there's any particular problem here.

Here's applicationContext.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd"
        default-autowire="byName" >

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyzzy" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
           <value>classpath:user-specific.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/dataSource"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="fooDAO" class="com.xyzzy.FooDAOImpl" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xyzzy" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>

            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xyzzy" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

All of the not-solely-for-testing classes (Foo, FooDAO, FooDAOImpl) are in the package com.xyzzy, and all of the testing ones (ContextTest, ContextTestHelper, ContextTestHelperImpl, ContextDuplicationException) are in com.xyzzy.test.

There are no @Transactional annotations on Foo, FooDAO or FooDAOImpl.  ContextTestHelperImpl is the only one specifying Transaction boundaries.

Any suggestions for how to fix this so that it behaves as it should?  (Is there something wrong with my choice of dataSource class, or transactionManager?  Are some of my settings in applicationContext.xml inconsistent or redundant?)

UPDATE:

DAO implementation class:

```java
@Repository("FooDAO")
public class FooDAOImpl implements FooDAO {
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo createFoo(int val) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setVal(val);
        saveFoo(foo);
        return foo;
    }

    void saveFoo(Foo foo) {
        hibernateTemplate.save(foo);
    }

    [... and many similar methods ...]
```

I also tried it with Propagation.REQUIRED (read somewhere that it will cause an exception early on if there's not a Transaction associated with the thread), but that does not change its behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have have 2 tests in a class. You are assuming those tests are run sequentially. Your are expecting an exact record count of either 1 or 0. The tests are run in parallel, thus conflicting with your expected result.

Change the logic so that each test uses it's own unique values (for inserts). Instead of comparing a record count based on select all (no criteria). Select from the database with criteria (add a where clause).

To summarize, the test runner is running the tests in parallel. You need to take that in to account and segregate test cases. Use unique values in each test case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.  I see the tests as running sequentially when I print out entry/exit to each method.  (And as you suggested, I changed the second test to use a different unique value, and it still failed in the same way.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would challenge the premise that:     <code>return new Foo[] { fooDAO.createFoo(val), fooDAO.createFoo(val) }; </code> performs 2 inserts in the same transaction. Wouldn't that occur in you DAO?? like: <code> entityManager.persist(s);  entityManager.persist(s);</code>. I would run the code through the debugger to test the premise. The database is only going to reject the second insert. So your premise solely on the 2 inserts occurring in a single transaction. Thus, I would verify that a single transaction performs both inserts. Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry :) typo. My comment should read: "So your premise relies solely on the 2 inserts occurring in a single transaction.". The premise is the transaction manager, not the database, rolls back the initial insert.

Comment: I do assume that the inserts happen in the same transaction, but isn't that what the Transactional annotation is supposed to do?  If I change the transaction to read-only, it fails immediately, so it does seem that the Transactional annotation is being caught and has some effect.  I thought that use of Spring management turned off Hibernate auto-commit.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting challenge. I am questioning where the Transactional annotation is placed (not whether, sorry). Shouldn't it go where the entity manager is committing/persisting? I would test by replacing the injected transaction with java source code. That way you guarantee single transaction (just as a proof concept).

Comment: Is there a transaction being injected in the DAO class? That is what I was trying to ask. I would run the java stated transaction (including a commit) through a debugger to verify expected behavior. Test where the transaction should occur. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: The DAO class has no "transactional" annotation, but it does inject a SessionFactory and builds a HibernateContext from that.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at your updated post and setup. To me, using JPA to manage the data is the way to go. You've configured a JPA entityManager, however, you aren't using it. See sample code here:http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ and my own project here https://github.com/lorinpa/book-site-jpa. You've done really great work. You can trim it down by using JPA on top of Hibernate (and Spring). Right now you are mixing native Hibernate and JPA. My project implements the same unique constraint you are trying to mode. So I hope that helps :)

Comment: OK, I took out the sessionFactory config, switched to using the EntityManager bean that I'd configured in ApplicationContext.xml.... and the problem persists.  Weird.  But over time the classes have changed so much that I'll probably just submit a fresh question.